# Can we determine the probability of finding an electron without a potential well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability

Can we determine the probability of finding electron in a region of space if there is no boundary condition?

For example, if the wall of a one-dimensional potential well is infinitely far away then is there a way that we can find the probability of finding the electron in a given region of space?

Answer (score 6):

I would rephrase the correct answer by Thatpotatoisaspy   as:

when there are no boundary conditions there are the plane wave solutions of the quantum mechanical equations. Plane waves go from -infinity to + infinity so they are not good for modeling the probability of  finding the electrons in our experiment. But, there exist [wave packets](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html), which can  model the probabily:

[image: wavepackets]

The calculation tools for computing the probabilities of interaction of elementary particles do not need such modeling as they use the [Feynman diagrams](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html#c2) of interactions, which have specific rules that write down the integrals from the diagrams, without a  need for modeling individual incoming particles, and they are quite good in their predictions for the probability of interactions.

Comment: My answer was very very brief so thank you for expanding on this.

Comment: The boundary conditions still exist, they are just different: boundedness as $|x|\to\infty$ (this will also let you find plane wave solutions).

Comment: @Ruslan yes, that is why I went directly to the plane wave solutions

Comment: My point is that without boundary conditions you have no restrictions on the wavefunction: e.g. it could be $\exp(x)$, which is obviously unphysical.

Comment: @Ruslan  probability has to be integrated to 1

Comment: @annav only for physically allowable states, but not for eigenstates in general (otherwise you lose all the continuous spectrum).

Comment: @Ruslan  An electron is a physical state afaik.  . Find" means "measure" inmy vocabulary

Answer (score 2):

I think it's important to point out that if a problem admits bound states, then there is *always* a boundary condition at infinity, which comes from demanding that the wave function go to zero as $x \to \pm \infty$.

It's interesting to note that for a particle in a box, the quantisation condition that leads to discrete solutions comes from demanding that the wave function vanish at (say) $x=0$ and $x=L$. Similarly, in problems like the harmonic oscillator or the hydrogen atom, the quantisation conditions arise by imposing the condition that the wave functions vanish at $\pm \infty$. (This is worked out in Griffiths' text.)

Now, the case that you mention in your question is essentially that of a free particle (a particle in a box with the walls infinitely far away), and as mentioned in [the answer by Thatpotatoisaspy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/523354/can-we-determine-the-probability-of-finding-an-electron-without-a-potential-well/523357#523357), you can construct a [wave packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet) to define the particle as being ''localised'' somewhere, and thus you *can* speak of a particle as having some probability of being found somewhere in space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A good example is a [wave packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet) for the free particle. The ordinary free particle solution is not normalisable, but you can construct another solution which is, the wave packet.