# Is the shape of the wavefunction of a particle in a free space always a 3D gaussian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Is the shape of the wavefunction of a particle in a free space at any particular time (thus a particle that is not subject to any external influence including the higgs field which is reponsible for its mass) always a 3D gaussian?

Comment: See [this question and answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/699390/83835).  The short story is that  Gaussian is a nice function to deal with, but it is just one possibility among an infinitude of (square-integrable) wave functions.

Comment: Assuming a Gaussian distribution is a spherical cow type of assumption. Cows aren't spherical, but assuming spherical cows can lead to oftentimes interesting and sometimes useful results. In simulation and modeling people assume a Gaussian distribution even when they **know** that strictly speaking that that assumption is invalid. For example, a distance sensor based on round trip time is oftentimes modeled as Gaussian. Distance is strictly non-negative, but a Gaussian distribution might result in a negative value. But that Gaussian assumption is close enough for horseshoes and hand grenades.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not always a Gaussian.

All it means for a particle to be a "free particle" is to not be confined in a potential. (i.e., V(x) = 0 in the Schrodinger Equation.)

Pick an initial state that your particle is in, now solve the differential equation

$$\begin{align}
 i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi = &H \psi \\
 = &(\frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x))\psi \\
 = &\frac{p^2}{2m} \psi \\
 = &-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi \\
\end{align}
$$

So if you crack open a numerical partial differential equation solver, or solve it analytically, you have your solution for the behavior of $\psi(x,y,z, t)$ as a function of 3D as a function of time.

If your initial condition isn't a gaussian, then your solution won't be either!

Answer (score 0):

The wavefunction is a solution of the relevant wave equation without a potential , Dirac for fermions, Klein Gordon for bosons, etc.

Wave equations' simplest solutions are plane waves, which are not good for describing a particle in free space, because , as it represents the probability of finding the particle, a plane wave cannot give a local probability , the particle could be anywhere in fourspace.

So for representing  non interacting free particles on uses the [wave packet solutions,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html)

[image: wave packet]

For calculating interactions particles one uses the Feynman diagrams of quantum field theory, where it is not necessary to use such a complication in the the wavefunction. Related answer of [mine here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/402793/which-experiment-clearly-shows-us-that-heisenberg-uncertainty-principle-is-ontol/402795#402795) and [here .](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/523354/can-we-determine-the-probability-of-finding-an-electron-without-a-potential-well/523372#523372)