# What is a 3d gaussian and does it describe a moving particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

How does it look? Is there any image?

Comment: where did you find such a concept?\

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/699411/is-the-shape-of-the-wavefunction-of-a-particle-in-a-free-space-always-a-3d-gauss

Comment: I think that in my answer in the link you give, there is an  image of the gaussian, and yes that would be in three dimensions, four if you go to relativistic equations.  That is probability distributions in space time for finding a free particle. It gets complicated see https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Quantum%20Mechanics/Miscellaneous%20Essays/Gaussian%20Wavepackets.pdf

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to point out that a 1-dimensional gaussian takes *two* dimensions to represent graphically, the x-axis (perhaps position) and the y axis (the distribution value at that position).

A 2-D gaussian takes 3 dimensions to represent graphically. The x-y position, and the z distribution value.
[![X and Y can be described as position, and the Z axis would be distribution or probability.][1]][1]

You can in fact have any mathematically described n-dimensioned gaussian; however, after 2 dimensions of independent variables, we 3-dimensional beings wouldn't be able to see all the information at once.

Now, as to whether a particle can be described as a 3D gaussian, I would say in almost all cases no. In quantum mechanics, particles are described not by position coordinates, but by distributed position functions (wave functions) that describe the likelihood of finding a particle at any one spot. How the wave function looks depends on the potential energy a particle finds itself. You could perhaps construct a gaussian wave (see [Gaussian Wave Packets][2]), but it in no way describes a quantum particle in general.

Comment: Thank for your answer. It all sounds great bit i still got no idea how it looks like even a 2D gaussian. I believe it lools like a hat? And 3D like a hard boiled egg -high propability inside and low in the peripherie? As is goes to the particle I meant free particle. My imperessioon is that the wavefunction spreads like blowing baloon and its crosssection looks like 1D gaussian at the initial momentum of release. Then the 1D waveacket dissipates quickly for massive particles.

Comment: I had a picture attached that didn't go through, but thats right. I think of a 2D gaussian as a hill, with the hilltop being high probability.

Comment: Additionally, a 3D gaussian would be a "fuzzy" egg, as it asymptotically reaches 0 at infinity.

Comment: Well that's the same as I imagine. Could you comment the pictire of the free particle? I think the baloon with 1d crosssection on the radiis is most appropriete not a 3d gaussian.